# Convert map[string][]string to []map[string]interface{}

Tags: go, gota

I have a tmp variable whose type is map[string][]string and I want to use LoadMaps feature of gota daraframe. But it only accepts []map[string]interface{}.
Now I want to find a way to convert map[string][]string to []map[string]interface{}.

```
func main() {
    input := [][]string{
            []string{"b", "3", "abc", "5.3"},
            []string{"a", "4", "efg", "9.1"},
            []string{"b", "4", "abc", "5.3"},
            []string{"c", "3", "hij", "5.5"},
            []string{"a", "2", "abc", "9.2"},
    }

    tmp := map[string][]string{}
    for _, slice := range input {
        if len(slice) <= 1 {
            continue
        }
        //fmt.Println(slice)
        tmp[slice[2]] = append(tmp[slice[2]], slice[0:2]...)
        fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(tmp))
    }


    df := dataframe.LoadMaps(tmp)

}
```

Comment: In short: You cannot. See https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

Comment: iterate and reassign??

Answer (score 0):

you could convert `map[string][]string`  to `map[string]interface{}` , then use append method to `[]map[string]interface{}`